# Outlook 2010 VBA change properties on a newly from exchange synced appointment

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010 I want to change certain properties in an appointment depending on what identifier is written in the subject line. This works nice as long as I change the appointment in Outlook and use the _changeitem event.

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items
...
Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
...
```

But now when an appointment is added on e.g. a phone and then being synced to Outlook from the Exchange Server I would need to do the same but the "_ItemChange" event doesn't fire.
My searches into the MS documentation weren't really successful.

Does anyone have some idea how to catch a newly from Exchange synced item (appointment) so some properties can be adjusted programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as it turns out, the _ItemAdd Event is fired. That will do.